# How to convert plain values with arrays into a data structure in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, unnest

I have this demo query that starts from a list of "author + articles" values:

```sql
VALUES
('author1', ARRAY[('title1', 'content1'), ('title2', 'content2')]),
('author2', ARRAY[('title3', 'content3'), ('title4', 'content4')])
```

I'd like to convert this into the following data structure:

| author | title | content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| author1 | title1 | content1 |
| author1 | title2 | content2 |
| author2 | title3 | content3 |
| author2 | title4 | content4 |

I've come this far:

```sql
WITH "raw_data" ("author", "articles") AS  (
    VALUES
        ('author1', ARRAY[('title1', 'content1'), ('title2', 'content2')]),
        ('author2', ARRAY[('title3', 'content3'), ('title4', 'content4')])
),
"articles" AS (
    SELECT "author", unnest("articles") AS "article" FROM "raw_data"
)
SELECT author, article FROM "articles";
```

But I get the following:

| author | article |
| --- | --- |
| author1 | (title1, content1) |
| author1 | (title2, content2) |
| author2 | (title3, content3) |
| author2 | (title4, content4) |

And I need to find a way to convert the record `(title2, content1)` into 2 distinct columns.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may achieve this by creating a custom type for your record and casting to it.

See example below

**Schema (PostgreSQL v13)**

---

**Query #1**

```
create type article as (title text, contents text);
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #2**

```
WITH "raw_data" ("author", "articles") AS  (
    VALUES
        ('author1', ARRAY[('title1', 'content1'), ('title2', 'content2')]),
        ('author2', ARRAY[('title3', 'content3'), ('title4', 'content4')])
),
"articles"  AS (
    SELECT "author", ((unnest("articles"))::text::article).* FROM "raw_data"
)
SELECT * FROM "articles";
```

| author | title | contents |
| --- | --- | --- |
| author1 | title1 | content1 |
| author1 | title2 | content2 |
| author2 | title3 | content3 |
| author2 | title4 | content4 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hLepYPyUxffuea2UBLbvk7/0)

Just breaking down the expression `((unnest("articles"))::text::article).*`

1. `(unnest("articles")` - converts your array to rows
2. `((unnest("articles"))::text` - casts each record to text (unable to cast directly to article at this time)
3. `(unnest("articles"))::text::article` - cast each record to your article type
4. `((unnest("articles"))::text::article).*` - expand or select all from your record to get both columns

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: Follow up question @ggordon : do you have any idea how to achieve a similar result starting from a single JSON document? 

(I'm preparing a JSON on PostgreSQL lecture and I'm putting together a few use-cases that are normally overlooked in favor of multiple queries and application logic)

Comment: You may create another question with some sample data and expected results and share the link here so that I and other S/O users may take a look at it

Comment: Btw, this is the resulting tutorial thanks to your help: https://github.com/marcopeg/amazing-postgresql/tree/main/projects/populate-nested-data-from-values-in-postgresql